# Typescript template literal for object key mapping

Tags: typescript, template-literals

I'm trying to create a generic type that would map the keys using template literals. In general i just want all the keys listed in the generic type to be present in the output type, but modified slightly. Something along the lines of:

```
type TFoobar = "foo" | "bar";

const foobar: TFlagDict<TFoobar> = {
    "foo_flag": true,
    "bar_flag": true
};
```

I have tried implementing it like so:

```
type TFlagDict<TProperties extends string> = {
    [key in TProperties]: {[k in `${key}_flag`]: boolean}
}[TProperties]
```

And while it does have a proper typing, it makes the properties optional (at least one is required, but there is nothing that enforces they are all present)

```
const foo: TFlagDict<TFoobar> = {
    "foo_flag": true
}; //valid, shouldnt be

const bar: TFlagDict<TFoobar> = {
    "bar_flag": true
}; //valid, shouldnt be

const foobar: TFlagDict<TFoobar> = {
    "foo_flag": true,
    "bar_flag": true
}; //valid
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You were close:

```js
type TFoobar = "foo" | "bar";

const foobar: TFlagDict<TFoobar> = {
    "foo_flag": true,
    "bar_flag": true
};

type TFlagDict<TProperties extends string> = {
    [key in TProperties as `${key}_flag`]: boolean // key remapping
}

type O = TFlagDict<TFoobar>
const foo: TFlagDict<TFoobar> = {
    "foo_flag": true
}; //error

const bar: TFlagDict<TFoobar> = {
    "bar_flag": true
}; //error

const foobar2: TFlagDict<TFoobar> = {
    "foo_flag": true,
    "bar_flag": true
}; //valid
```

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/wggplw)

You are allowed to use `as` inside iterator. See [docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html#key-remapping-via-as) for more context

Comment: Do you know of a way to do the opposite? Instead of extending the key to shorten it? let's say key can `Key extends '${infer Parent}.${infer Leaf}'` and we would make the Parent a key

Comment: But you already know how to do it. `Key extends '${infer Parent}.${infer Leaf}'` should work. Could you please provide a link to ts playground with comments ?

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html#key-remapping-via-as

Answer (score 2):

You can use `TFooBar` instead of `key` to enforce such validation:

```
type TFlagDict<TProperties extends string> = {
    [key in TProperties]: {[k in `${TFoobar}_flag`]: boolean}
}[TProperties]
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAKgYgewQIwIYCcoF4oCIBmSuUAPnmurgNwBQdokscANqgOYAiAlgMbAA8MAAroEkdMC4QAzlAgAPYBAB2AE1nTg6LsrYA%20bFADeNKGagBtANYQQUHbBFiIEqdIC6ALmPX7yqAAGACRGwqLikjIAvgD6%20KxsAV5QyEjMEKjKUTRRFmHOrjLudDwIyppQhAje8AncfIKIKBgGOCbmeFVxCbjeWgCuEDlUUAD0owBuqMxcqgA0UNIAFgj9zKrKwClDNKXlWxQ1LOz1AvBIFK3Gpua4FN3svVADQ1Ej41Mz84sraxsHOz2FSqhyYdV4Zyal0M7VuXXijz66EGcxuZjuGAebCeL2GY0m01mQA)